# How can I plot string as x axis insted of numbers in gnuplot?

Tags: bash

I have two column, first consists of vocabularies and the second includes numbers. How can I set gnuplot in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xtic` or `xticlabels` ex. given `file.dat`

```
foo 1.23
bar 4.56
baz 7.89
```

then

```
gnuplot -p -e 'plot "file.dat" using 2:xtic(1) title "foobar"'
```

gives

[image]

Comment: And if we have two string columns how can it possible?

Comment: @msndm I don't really understand what you are asking - if you have multiple *dependent* variables, you can use one of the methods described here [gnuplot: plotting a file with 4 columns all on y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073232/gnuplot-plotting-a-file-with-4-columns-all-on-y-axis). If you are asking about the case where both the independent and dependent variable are categorical, then I'm not sure an XY chart is appropriate for that.